# Restore git repo from a pack file

Tags: git

I am taking over some project, and I don't have a proper git repo but rather a *pack-7dab97d983eeb36321c680bee7fde43688334f52.pack* file. Can I restore a working git repository from it? And how?

Comment: Have you tried git-unpack - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-unpack-objects

Answer (score 9, accepted):

pack file contains only commits, so you don't have branch names, you have to guess them. A good starting points would be dangling commits.

- create an empty repository
- copy the pack to .git/objects/pack/
- probably index the pack (I'm not sure if it needed or not)
- run `git fsck --lost-found`
- pick from found tips your probable branches

Note that it would fail if the pack file is only one of several from the original repository, as it may depend on objects which you don't have

Comment: There was just one dangling commit, so the choice for `master` was pretty easy. Thanks a lot!

Comment: last step would be ```git branch somebranchname SHA1_OF_dangling_commit ```

Answer (score 4):

There are two questions you could be asking:

1. Can I restore *the original* repository, with all its branch names?
2. Can I restore *some sort of repository, that may or may not be good enough for some purpose?*

The answer to question 1 is *no*.

The answer to question 2 is *maybe, even fairly likely yes, as long as it's not a "thin" pack*.

[max630's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49617285/1256452) gives a method by which you can implement Answer 2, along with the reason you can't implement Answer 1: a repository consists, in essence, of *two* databases.  One of these databases is *name-to-hash-ID.*  You lack this database entirely: you have no *names*.

The other database consists of *objects:* commits, and supporting objects.  You do have some of these.

Specifically, a *pack file* is a collection of objects.  A repository may use more than one pack file, and/or may contain *loose* (unpacked) objects.  Having a pack file therefore does not guarantee that you have *all* the objects that go with that repository: you might have only *some* of the objects.

For most pack files, however, there's a second guarantee: pack files use [delta-compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding) to save space, but will only delta-compress against other objects contained within *the same* pack file.  That means this pack file is independent of any other pack files that may have made up the complete object database: you may have an incomplete slice, but you can at least extract all the objects.

This rule is violated for *thin* packs: a thin pack is (defined as) a pack in which some object(s) are missing, so that the pack is not generally usable.  You may have some objects within such a file that are complete—that refer only to other objects in the same file, or aren't delta-compressed at all—but in general thin packs won't have enough objects to be useful for most purposes.